Is This SQL Running Outer Joins and Parentheses for A Good Reason?
I find the from clause below confusing.  Is this from clause setup in an excellent way database engineers should all understand?  The features confusing me are:

All left outer joins. Almost all the joins would be valid as inner
joins. Why has left outer join been favored?
The left outer joins seem to be part of a nest of parentheses. I
don't understand why  that is desirable or favorable. I get
understandable results by removing the parenthesis, is that a
problem?
Why all the " quotation marks?

I have changed the table and field names to protect the privacy of my employer.
SELECT KITTEN_BOWL.ID
  FROM (((((((("PUBLIC"."KITTEN_BOWL"          "KITTEN_BOWL"
               LEFT OUTER JOIN
               "PUBLIC"."ZC_KITTEN_CLAW_TYPE"  "ZC_KITTEN_CLAW_TYPE"
               ON "KITTEN_BOWL"."KITTEN_CLAW_TYPE_C" =
                  "ZC_KITTEN_CLAW_TYPE"."KITTEN_CLAW_TYPE_C")
              LEFT OUTER JOIN
              "PUBLIC"."KNOWLEDGE_FREEDOM"     "KNOWLEDGE_FREEDOM_coll"
              ON "KITTEN_BOWL"."KITTEN_COLL_FREEDOMT_PUBLIC_CODE" =
                 "KNOWLEDGE_FREEDOM_coll"."PRPUBLIC_CODEE_PUBLIC_CODE")
             LEFT OUTER JOIN
             "PUBLIC"."KNOWLEDGE_EMP"          "KNOWLEDGE_EMP"
             ON "KITTEN_BOWL"."KITTEN_COLL_BY_PUBLIC_CODE" =
                "KNOWLEDGE_EMP"."USER_PUBLIC_CODE")
            LEFT OUTER JOIN
            "PUBLIC"."KITTEN_DECISION_REL"     "KITTEN_DECISION_REL"
            ON "KITTEN_BOWL"."KITTENIMEN_PUBLIC_CODE" =
               "KITTEN_DECISION_REL"."KITTENIMEN_PUBLIC_CODE")
           LEFT OUTER JOIN
           "KNOWLEDGE"."SELF"                  "SELF"
           ON "KITTEN_BOWL"."KITTEN_EPT_FRIEND_PUBLIC_CODE" = "SELF"."FRIEND_PUBLIC_CODE")
          LEFT OUTER JOIN
          "PUBLIC"."KNOWLEDGE_FREEDOM"         "KNOWLEDGE_FREEDOM_acc_from"
          ON "KITTEN_DECISION_REL"."ACC_FROM_FREEDOM_PUBLIC_CODE" =
             "KNOWLEDGE_FREEDOM_acc_from"."PRPUBLIC_CODEE_PUBLIC_CODE")
         LEFT OUTER JOIN
         "KNOWLEDGE"."DECISION_MSTR_BOWL"      "DECISION_MSTR_BOWL"
         ON "KITTEN_DECISION_REL"."KITTEN_TST_PUBLIC_CODE" =
            "DECISION_MSTR_BOWL"."DECISION_PUBLIC_CODE")
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
        "KNOWLEDGE"."HOMEWORK_ADVANCEMENT_2"   "HOMEWORK_ADVANCEMENT_2"
        ON "KITTEN_DECISION_REL"."KITTEN_TST_HOMEWORK_PUBLIC_CODE" =
           "HOMEWORK_ADVANCEMENT_2"."HOMEWORK_ADVANCEMENT_PUBLIC_CODE")
       LEFT OUTER JOIN "KNOWLEDGE"."KNOWLEDGE_FREEDOM" "KNOWLEDGE_FREEDOM_ord"
          ON "HOMEWORK_ADVANCEMENT_2"."FRIEND_LOC_PUBLIC_CODE" =
             "KNOWLEDGE_FREEDOM_ord"."PRPUBLIC_CODEE_PUBLIC_CODE"


Any guess is conjecture. Working out why on earth the prior dev did it this way is a common pastime. This code was probably generated by something (Cognos?) and copy pasted

This is clearly code-generated SQL, not something a human would write. Code generators often do things that a human wouldn't, because they are designed to be modular and make few assumptions about object names and the inter-relationships between query blocks.


It is not that outer joins are favored; they exist for a reason, so that query returns rows even though there's no match in between. I presume you should know the data to understand whether you should (or not) use outer joins. The author probably knows it.

Nested parenthesis: as far as I can tell, they are useless here.

Quotation marks: useless as well at most places. In Oracle, we normally don't use them. Names are - in data dictionary - stored in uppercase, regardless of how you create tables, procedures, columns ... you can use any letter case you want and reference them any way you want unless you enclose them into double quotes - in that case, you must use double quotes and match names exactly as you used them when creating those objects.
Example which illustrates it - in code you posted - is "KNOWLEDGE_FREEDOM_coll" where everything is in upper case, except the last part of the name (unless it was you, who masked names).



If that realy is the code, with just that one ID column selected and without the Where clause or anything else from any of left joined tables, then the same result could be achieved using:
Select ID From KITTEN_BOWL;

It is like this:
WITH
    from_tbl AS
        ( Select 1 "ID", 110 "A_NUMBER", 'A' "A_LETTER" From Dual Union All
          Select 2 "ID", 120 "A_NUMBER", 'B' "A_LETTER" From Dual Union All
          Select 3 "ID", 130 "A_NUMBER", 'C' "A_LETTER" From Dual 
        ), 
    left_tbl AS 
        ( Select 101 "ID", 9 "FROM_TBL_ID", 'X' "LEFT_LETTER" From Dual Union All
          Select 102 "ID", 1 "FROM_TBL_ID", 'Y' "LEFT_LETTER" From Dual Union All
          Select 103 "ID", 7 "FROM_TBL_ID", 'Z' "LEFT_LETTER" From Dual 
        )
Select    ft.ID
From      from_tbl ft
Left Join left_tbl lt ON(lt.FROM_TBL_ID = ft.ID)

--  R e s u l t 
    ID
------
     1
     2
     3

The same result gives you the below code
Select ID From from_tbl

About Left Join:

use it when there are rows in the From table that have no matching rows in left joined table but you still want to fetch the From table rows

Select    ft.ID, ft.A_NUMBER, ft.A_LETTER, lt.LEFT_LETTER
From      from_tbl ft
Left Join left_tbl lt ON(lt.FROM_TBL_ID = ft.ID)
/*  R e s u l t :
        ID   A_NUMBER A_LETTER LEFT_LETTER
---------- ---------- -------- -----------
         1        110 A        Y
         2        120 B                    
         3        130 C                    */

If you use Inner Join instead of Left Join then it will act as a filter selecting just the matching rows:
Select     ft.ID, ft.A_NUMBER, ft.A_LETTER, lt.LEFT_LETTER
From       from_tbl ft
Inner Join left_tbl lt ON(lt.FROM_TBL_ID = ft.ID)
/*  R e s u l t :
        ID   A_NUMBER A_LETTER LEFT_LETTER
---------- ---------- -------- -----------
         1        110 A        Y           */


You could use Left Join to select just the rows that don't have a match (see the Where clause)

Select    ft.ID, ft.A_NUMBER, ft.A_LETTER, lt.LEFT_LETTER
From      from_tbl ft
Left Join left_tbl lt ON(lt.FROM_TBL_ID = ft.ID)
Where     lt.ID Is Null
/*  R e s u l t :
        ID   A_NUMBER A_LETTER LEFT_LETTER
---------- ---------- -------- -----------
         2        120 B                    
         3        130 C                    */

About quotations and parenthesis - I have nothing to add to Littlefoot's answer.

The result is only the same as the simple select ID from from_tbl if all the relationships are (at most) 1:1. If one of the left-joined tables has more than one entry for one of those IDs then the original will get duplicates - fiddle.

@AlexPoole That is true. I think that the OP shortened the code, though.  Just don't see the point  or usefullness of just that ID selected whether unique or with duplicates. There must be something else within the code or the code is used with something else that we don't  know about.

Yeah, agree it doesn't make sense either way *8-)

The question is about the from clause.  To avoid wasting time on the select and where clauses, the details of those clauses were excluded from the sql posted with this question.

@DanAllen Thanks, that makes sense. Then my answer offers the basic difference between Inner and Left (Outer) join implementation (as Littlefoot mentioned - not favoured but for a reason). What's the reason we could not know without context and data. Look in your code for what is selected and/or conditioned from left joined tables columns to find the reason for Left joins. Regarding quotes and parenthesis (agreed with Littlefoot's answer) - you don't need them.



Why has left outer join been favored?


SQL joins are explained in this question.
LEFT OUTER JOIN will get all the rows from the left-table (driving table) and will find those that match (based on the ON clause) and join them from the right-table and where there are no matches will populate the result set for the right-table's columns in the non-matching rows with NULL values.
INNER JOIN will only get the rows where there exists matches (based on the ON clause) between both tables.
They do different things. Don't replace LEFT OUTER JOIN with INNER JOIN unless you are certain that you are never going to get rows in the left-table that are not matched by the right-table. For that, you need to understand the business logic that you are implementing.


The left outer joins seem to be part of a nest of parentheses.


Parentheses are used to change precedence in an order of operations.
Sometimes excess parentheses are irrelevant:
SELECT (((((value))))) FROM table_name;

is identical to:
SELECT value FROM table_name;

Sometimes parentheses are relevant (i.e. they are not "excess") and change the precedence in the order of operations:
SELECT (1 + 2)*3 FROM DUAL;

So + is evaluated before * in that expression but, without the brackets the order of operations would be reversed.

Similar to using brackets in expressions, there is a little used feature where you can use brackets to change the precedence of joins in the FROM clause.
SELECT *
FROM   a
       LEFT OUTER JOIN b
       ON a.thing = b.a_thing
       INNER JOIN c
       ON b.other = c.b_other;

Which, for the sample data:
CREATE TABLE a (thing, a_value) AS
SELECT 1, 'A1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'A2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'A3' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'A4' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 'A5' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE b (a_thing, other, b_value) AS
SELECT 3, 30, 'B3' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 40, 'B4' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 50, 'B5' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE c (b_other, c_value) AS
SELECT 30, 'C3' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 40, 'C4' FROM DUAL;

Outputs:



THING
A_VALUE
A_THING
OTHER
B_VALUE
B_OTHER
C_VALUE




3
A3
3
30
B3
30
C3


4
A4
4
40
B4
40
C4



If you want to enforce that the INNER JOIN is performed before the OUTER JOIN then you could rewrite it by reversing the join order and using RIGHT OUTER JOIN:
SELECT *
FROM   b
       INNER JOIN c
       ON b.other = c.b_other
       RIGHT OUTER JOIN a
       ON a.thing = b.a_thing;

(Note: this changes the order of the columns in SELECT *.)
Or by using a nested SELECT statement:
SELECT *
FROM   a
       LEFT OUTER JOIN (
         SELECT *
         FROM   b
                INNER JOIN c
                ON b.other = c.b_other
       ) bc
       ON a.thing = bc.a_thing;

or you can use parentheses in the statement:
SELECT *
FROM   a
       LEFT OUTER JOIN (
         b
         INNER JOIN c
         ON b.other = c.b_other
       )
       ON a.thing = b.a_thing;

This is less to type, compared to using a nested SELECT, and also keeps the aliases b and c available in the outer-query.
All three of those queries output:



THING
A_VALUE
A_THING
OTHER
B_VALUE
B_OTHER
C_VALUE




3
A3
3
30
B3
30
C3


4
A4
4
40
B4
40
C4


2
A2
null
null
null
null
null


5
A5
null
null
null
null
null


1
A1
null
null
null
null
null



(Note: As already mentioned, the RIGHT OUTER JOIN query puts the THING and A_VALUE columns last instead of first but the data is identical.)
If you want to find out whether your query can be rewritten without the parentheses then you can consider whether the parentheses are enforcing an order of joins from the first listed sequentially through to the last; in which case the parentheses are (probably) excess and can be removed. Or, if the parentheses are enforcing a different order of operations; in which case the parentheses are (probably) not excess and should be considered very carefully before attempting to remove them.
In your case, the parentheses enforce the order of joins in the order they were written so removing the parentheses should have no effect on the statement.
If you want to confirm this then compare the EXPLAIN PLANs for the statements with- and without-parentheses.
I.e.
EXPLAIN PLAN FOR
SELECT *
FROM   ((((
         (((
           a
           LEFT OUTER JOIN b
           ON a.thing = b.a_thing
         )))
         INNER JOIN c
         ON b.other = c.b_other
       ))));

SELECT PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT FROM TABLE(DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY());

and:
EXPLAIN PLAN FOR
SELECT *
FROM   a
       LEFT OUTER JOIN b
       ON a.thing = b.a_thing
       INNER JOIN c
       ON b.other = c.b_other;

SELECT PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT FROM TABLE(DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY());

Both generate the same explain plans. (Similarly, the other 3 queries - using RIGHT OUTER JOIN, a nested SELECT and parenthesis around the INNER JOIN - all generate explain plans that are identical to each other but different to when there are no parentheses.)
This fiddle gives example of the queries used in this answer and compares the EXPLAIN PLANs for different join precedences.



Why all the " quotation marks?


Oracle database are case-sensitive; however their default behaviour is to convert all identifiers to upper-case which makes it appear that they are case-insensitive.
Therefore:
SELECT DUMMY FROM DUAL;
SELECT dummy FROM dual;
SELECT DuMmY FROM dUaL;
SELECT Dummy FROM Dual;

are all identical.
Quoted-identifiers prevent the SQL engine from changing the case to upper-case - enforcing the case-sensitivity of the database.
So:
SELECT "DUMMY" FROM "DUAL";

would be identical to the previous, unquoted, statements but:
SELECT "dummy" FROM "dual";
SELECT "DuMmY" FROM "dUaL";
SELECT "Dummy" FROM "Dual";

Would be three different statements looking for 3 different tables each containing 3 different columns.
In your case, since the identifiers are all in upper-case then removing the quotes would change identifiers such as "KNOWLEDGE_FREEDOM_coll" from being case-sensitive and having mixed-case to being upper-case. However, since these are local aliases in the query (and not identifiers for tables or columns) then if you remove the quotes everywhere then it should have no effect.

The question stated that inner joins are valid for this data set for most of the joins included.  Is there a reason to doubt the truth of that?  If inner joins are appropriate for all except one case, how can this answer contribute to answering the questions in the op?

@DanAllen The main thrust of this answer was to address the point on parentheses where Littlefoot's answer is incomplete. Parentheses in the FROM clause have a specific meaning (modifying the order of precedence) and can modify the explain plan - in your case removing the brackets may not have any effect but equally the optimiser may choose to join the tables in a different order to the top-to-bottom order written in the query and the brackets are there to ensure that that order of precedence is maintained. As stated, you need to check the EXPLAIN PLANs to tell if there is a difference.
